# Surface represented by the equation $x^2-2y^2+3z^2+5yz-6xz-4xy+8x-19y-2z-20=0$

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

I have the following second degree equation in $x,y$ & $z$:
$x^2-2y^2+3z^2+5yz-6xz-4xy+8x-19y-2z-20=0$
I calculated the discriminating cubic as:
$k^3-4k^2-97k-190=0$

The roots of this equation are  distinct.  The question says that it represents a cone having vertex at$(1,-2,3)$.

As a cone is a surface of revolution, two roots of the discriminating cubic should be zero. But that's not the case here. So this equation can't represent a cone.

Am I correct in asserting this? Can the equation represent a cone even without having two equal roots? Please suggest.

Comment: Rewrite to $(x-1)^2-4(x-1)(y+2)-2(y+2)^2-6(x-1)(z-3)+5(y+2)(z-3)+3(z-3)^2=0.$ This is a cone, since it's a translate of a homogeneous form with eigenvalues of the corresponding matrix $-1.151810481120533, -3.230672438055271, 6.382482919175805$.

Comment: Here's an [interactive 3D plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtj91uwyAMhe95Ct8VKHT5Wae0Gq_SKmu6DikJWZISzNPPsCIhn08-tnx8O_NdUKjiTjAfFHikH8FAqUBXCmq2JTgy1t2_oeNkIUcUZwb05vv6nEdYfueV86B9EJcK9sBRe3zJqH0kKeANNsbsMPX2Ztfr1Lu1pnVk0lBJzOZaxkvFSBwlykiNDxlyfaeKqdHIQFieJOax1KsKxYD7oDe6POw3oYgwE74oZoqJGN38sG40fTt8dS3k7OccjIT4NCVZbq53s-Gd-ldDOy2Hn8Wn6XT3dXJ2XBdTNoUCN7WUB01xaMQffypc9A==&lang=sage) of your elliptical cones, coloured according to the distance from the vertex. Change `w` to change the plot size, increase `plot_points` to get higher resolution.

Answer (score 1):

if you take $a=x-1, b = y+2, c=z-3$  you arrive at
$$  a^2 - 2 b^2 + 3 c^2 + 5 bc -6 ca -4 ab = 0. $$
It is this $0$ on the right hand side that says the object is a cone (over an ellipse, not a circle). Think about it: if you had $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$  you would have a circular cone. if you had $x^2 + 2y^2 - z^2 = 0$  you would have an
elliptical cone, as each choice of $z$ leads to a constant value for $x^2 + 2 y^2$

The fact that we get a quadratic form equal to zero comes from the final diagonal element $0$ in $D$ in these expressions:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 & 8 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 4 & 5 &  - 19 \\ 
 - 6 & 5 & 6 &  - 2 \\ 
8 &  - 19 &  - 2 &  - 40 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 }  &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 12 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 95 }{ 12 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 12 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 95 }{ 12 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 12 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 4 &  - 6 & 8 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 4 & 5 &  - 19 \\ 
 - 6 & 5 & 6 &  - 2 \\ 
8 &  - 19 &  - 2 &  - 40 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

We can parametrize all integer solutions in four ways as
$$
\begin{array}{} a=3u^2 +5uv-2v^2 \\  b=-2u^2 +4uv+v^2 \\  c=u^2 +2uv-5v^2 \; . \end{array}  $$

OR
$$
\begin{array}{} a=7uv-4v^2 \\  b=-u^2 +2uv+5v^2 \\  c=2u^2 +4uv-v^2 \; . \end{array}  $$
OR
$$
\begin{array}{} a=7uv-8v^2 \\  b=3u^2 -6uv+v^2 \\  c=u^2 +4uv-2v^2 \; . \end{array}  $$

OR$$
\begin{array}{} a=2u^2 +uv-6v^2 \\  b=u^2 +6uv+3v^2 \\  c=3u^2 -2v^2 \; . \end{array}  $$

in the following, I named the four (u,v) recipes with letters A,B,C,D. If the triple produced had $a < 0,$ I printed $-a,-b,-c$

```
     a         b         c          u    v
     0         1        -2
     0        -1         2
     0         1        -2   B      1    0
     0         3         1
     0        -3        -1
     0         3         1   C      1    0
     1         2        -3
     1         2        -3   C      1    1
     2         1         3
     2         1         3   D      1    0
     2        -1         5
     2        -1         5   A      0    1
     2       -23        -6
     2       -23        -6   B      1    2
     3       -10        -1
     3       -10        -1   D      1    1
     3        -2         1
     3        -2         1   A      1    0
     3         6         5
     3         6         5   B      1    1
     4        19        10
     4        19        10   D      2    1
     4        -5         1
     4        -5         1   B      0    1
     4         5         6
     4         5         6   A      1   -1
     5         2        -1
     5         2        -1   D      1   -1
     6         1        10
     6         1        10   C      2    1
     6         3        -2
     6        -3         2
     6         3        -2   A      1    1
     6        -3         2   D      0    1
     6        53        23
     6        53        23   B      2    3
     8        -1         2
     8        -1         2   C      0    1
     9       -30        71
     9       -30        71   A      1    4
     9        -6        25
     9        -6        25   D      3   -1
    10       -29        -2
    10       -29        -2   A      3   -1
    10       -47       106
    10       -47       106   C      6    5
    11        -2         3
    11        -2         3   B      1   -1
    11        38        23
    11        38        23   A      3   -2
    12        15       -19
    12        15       -19   D      3   -2
    12       -15        46
    12       -15        46   C      4    3
    12       -29        73
    12       -29        73   C      5    4
    12        57      -101
    12        57      -101   A      2    5
    13        10        19
    13        10        19   C      3    1
    15         6        23
    15         6        23   A      1   -2
    16       -23        67
    16       -23        67   D      5   -2
    17         2        29
    17         2        29   B      3    1
    17       -86       -15
    17       -86       -15   A      5   -2
    18       101        50
    18       101        50   A      5   -3
    18         3         1
    18         3         1   B      2   -1
    18         5        -1
    18         5        -1   C      1    2
    20         1         3
    20         1         3   A      2    1
    22       -25         6
    22       -25         6   C      2   -1
    22       -43       114
    22       -43       114   A      1    5
    22        -5        46
    22        -5        46   D      4   -1
    24        -1         5
    24        -1         5   D      1   -2
    24        25       -29
    24        25       -29   A      2    3
    24        -3        47
    24        -3        47   B      4    1
    26        23        38
    26        23        38   B      3    2
    26       -47         3
    26       -47         3   A      4   -1
    26        71      -115
    26        71      -115   D      7   -4
    27        46        43
    27        46        43   C      5    1
    29       -46         5
    29       -46         5   C      3   -1
    30        43        46
    30        43        46   D      4    1
    30        71        53
    30        71        53   A      4   -3
    31       -10        69
    31       -10        69   B      5    1
    32        19       -15
    32        19       -15   B      4   -1
    33        -6        67
    33        -6        67   C      5    3
    34        29       -30
    34        29       -30   D      4   -3
    34        73        58
    34        73        58   C      6    1
    36        23        53
    36        23        53   A      2   -3
    36       -73         2
    36       -73         2   C      4   -1
    36       -87        -2
    36       -87        -2   B      1    4
    36        97        67
    36        97        67   D      5    2
    39        -2        73
    39        -2        73   D      5   -1
    39        30       -29
    39        30       -29   B      5   -1
    40       -67         6
    40       -67         6   D      2    3
    41       106        75
    41       106        75   C      7    1
    43      -106        -3
    43      -106        -3   C      5   -1
    44        29       -25
    44        29       -25   C      3    4
    46       -19        15
    46       -19        15   C      1   -2
    46        43       -47
    46        43       -47   B      6   -1
    48        53        71
    48        53        71   B      4    3
    48       -69        10
    48       -69        10   A      5   -1
    49        10         1
    49        10         1   A      3    2
    49         2        87
    49         2        87   A      1   -4
    49       -46        15
    49       -46        15   D      1    3
    49        58        73
    49        58        73   D      5    1
    51         6         5
    51         6         5   C      1    3
    52         5         6
    52         5         6   D      2   -3
    52        67       -86
    52        67       -86   A      3    5
    53        58       -69
    53        58       -69   B      7   -1
    54        15        86
    54        15        86   B      5    2
    55        46       -47
    55        46       -47   A      3    4
    58         1        10
    58         1        10   B      3   -2
    60         3       106
    60         3       106   D      6   -1
    60        47       -46
    60        47       -46   C      4    5
    66       -15        19
    66       -15        19   A      4    1
    66        47       -43
    66        47       -43   D      5   -4
    66        67        97
    66        67        97   C      7    2
    67        94      -125
    67        94      -125   B      9   -1
    69        50       101
    69        50       101   B      5    3
    72        75       106
    72        75       106   D      6    1
    74       -67        23
    74       -67        23   C      3   -2
    78       -29        25
    78       -29        25   B      2   -3
    78        69       -73
    78        69       -73   C      5    6
    86        25        -6
    86        25        -6   B      5   -2
    87        86       -97
    87        86       -97   D      7   -5
    90       -73        29
    90       -73        29   D      1    4
    92       -71        30
    92       -71        30   B      1   -4
    93       -30        29
    93       -30        29   C      1   -3
    98       -25        29
    98       -25        29   D      1   -4
    98       -29        30
    98       -29        30   A      5    1
    98        73       -69
    98        73       -69   A      4    5
    98        95      -106
    98        95      -106   C      6    7
   108        69       -58
   108        69       -58   D      6   -5
   117        -6        25
   117        -6        25   A      5    2
    a          b        c           u    v
```

Comment: Does this mean that two roots of the discriminating cubic are equal in case of a right circular cone only?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT I have no idea. If you have a link to something that discusses the cubic you like, I will look at it. Meanwhile, there was a comment with the eigenvalues of the 3 by 3 symmetric matrix (after translating), and the two eigenvalues with the same $\pm$ sign are not of the same magnitude. So not a cone of revolution, rater a cone on an ellipse.